# When does WebComponent adoptedCallback fire?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

On MDN documentation, I see a function that WebComponents can implement called `adoptedCallback`. MDNs documentation states:

"Invoked when the custom element is moved to a new document."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/512

What does it mean that the custom element has moved to a new document? Under what circumstances should I implement this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `adoptedCallback(`) method is called when a Custom Element is moved from one HTML document to another one with the [`adoptNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode) method.

You will meet this use case when you have `<iframe>` elements in you page: each page will have its own HTML document, the main page and every pages in `<iframe>` elements.

When you move an element from one frame to another (or to the mail document), its `ownerDocument` is updated with the new [`HTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) reference but the element is not destructed and created. That means that the `constructor()` method will not be called.

---

You should implement this method only if your custom element will be used in a multi-document context and when you need to perform some special operations that should not be done in `connectedCallback()`, for example interactions with the owner document, the main document, or other elements.

Example: if you want to display a special interaction when the element is added to the document, but not when is originally inside it, you won't do it in `constructor()` or in `connectedCallback()`, but you can do it in `adoptedCallback()`.

```
adoptedCallback() {
    //change the color to red for 2 seconds
    var slot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("slot")
    slot.classList.add( "red" )
    setTimeout( () => slot.classList.remove( "red" ), 2000)
}
```

---

When you create a custom element, its callbacks are called in this order: `constructor` > `connectedCallback`

When you move a custom element whith `adoptNode()`, the callback are called in this order: `disconnectedCallback` (with `ownerDocument` set from source document) > `adoptedCallback` (with `ownerDocument` set from new document) > `connectedCallback`.

When you clone a custom element whith `importNode()`, the callback are called in that order: `constructor`  > `connectedCallback`.

Note that `connectedCallback()` is called when a new custom element is created, but also when it is moved. That's why you should not perform one-time or expensive initializations, like data loading, in the method.

---

You can deal with multiple documents in other situations, for example when you load HTML documents via HTML Imports.

Comment: In regards to the order of custom element callbacks (reactions), it is accurate that `constructor` is called before `connectedCallback` when you "create" (upgrade) a custom element, but `attributeChangedCallback` will run in between these two if one of the observed attributes changes during the upgrade: `constructor` > `attributeChangedCallback` > `connectedCallback`.