# What do we need to do in a Custom Element's adoptedCallback?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I've read various docs on Custom Elements and `adoptedCallback`, which say things like "called when the element is adopted into another document, i.e. when someone calls Document.importNode(customElement)". But this is not very much information.

What do I actually need adoptedCallback for? In other words, what will `adoptedCallback` be useful for in particular? What are some practical examples? What would a custom element author specifically want to achieve with `adoptedCallback`? What are scenarios that many custom element authors aren't thinking about, but that they should consider and handle in `adoptedCallback`?

Comment: See Supersharps answer from a year ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995139/when-does-webcomponent-adoptedcallback-fire And also helpful: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

Answer (score 2):

The main use case that I see is when you want to move some custom elements.

- If you have a custom element in an `<iframe>` and want it to move to another `<iframe>` or to the main document, you may want to realize some operations when the custom element owner document has changed, but not when the custom element was moved inside the same `<iframe>` or document.

Example: a IDE with drag and drop from the toolbar to the target HTML document.

- Another use case, you may need to proceed to some expensive operations (calculation, data loading) in the custom element only one time when you import it (in `adoptedCallck()`), not everytime you connect it (in `connectedCallback()`).

Example: a sheet/table with remote data.

It was also the case with HTML Imports but now it's less relevant.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the usefulness of what you describe. I can easily check if some data on `this.ownerDocument` or `this.ownerDocument.defaultView` is already loaded, in `connectedCallback`, and if it isn't then I can load it. We shouldn't rely on globals anyways. I don't see the point of `adoptedCallback` yet. Are there any useful examples somewhere that show where `adoptedCallback` really shines?